# Coldfusion autosuggest interfering with my jquery "change" handler?

Tags: jquery, events, coldfusion, autosuggest

I'm using a ColdFusion autosuggest for my UserID field. When a user starts to type in a UserID, a list of user ids pops up (populated by a cfc function). Sample code:

```
<cfinput name="userID" type="text" value="#userID#" autoSuggest="cfc:Utilities.suggestUser({cfautosuggestvalue})" matchcontains="true" />
```

I want to fire a handler when I choose one of the values in the autosuggest, so that I can use the selected value elsewhere. JQuery code:

```
$('#userID').change(function(){
    var userID = $(this).val();
    $('#otherUserIDField').html(userID);
});
```

The problem is, when I click on an item in the autosuggest list, the change event is fired before the selected entry is injected into the form field. For example, if I'm looking for user "123456" and I start typing "123" and then see it in the autosuggest list, I click on "123456" in the autosuggest list and the change event is fired, while the value of the form field is still only "123". I have tried adding a delay (`$('#otherUserIDField').delay(1000).html(userID);`), but it didn't help. Is there any other event I can use? Is there any way around this?

How can I execute code only after an autosuggestion was picked?

Comment: `.delay(1000)` is a dummy animation, it doesn't delay your `.html` call

Comment: FYI - as a bit of unasked for advice (ha) - I would stick with jQuery and eschew cfform. cfform is ok for basic prototyping but I always end up hacking it to pieces to get it to do what I want. jquery is much richer and usually has "the" piece that I need for a given behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the `setTimeout` method. As @Esailija mentioned in a comment, the `delay` function doesn't actually delay the html call. I couldn't use "this" with the new code as the delay causes the focus to no longer be on the textbox.

```
$('#userID').change(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
            $('#otherUserIDField').html($('#userID').val());
        }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: As someone who also used this to get around the same problem, I feel it's important to note that you can't pass information out of the setTimeout function, so code carefully if you need to call your code wrapped in setTimeout for more than one thing.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would use jQuery stand alone rather then the inbuilt ColdFusion ajax.  Here is a good example of this in action with a working demo: http://jacktraynor.blogspot.com.au/2012/02/jquery-autocomplete-using-coldfusion.html